# Flutter Failed to build iOS app ld: truncated fat fileld: truncated fat file

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

When i try to archive the flutter IOS version i am getting below error.
I updated the pod by using `pod update` and removed the cocoa caches.
I used `flutter clean` and `flutter build ios` to rebuild but still getting this error

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    ld: truncated fat file. Slice from 208257024 to 389831920 is past end of file with length 382730240 file
    '/Users/bilalrabbi/Desktop/tools/project11/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework/Flutter' for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
```

Answer (score 1):

By running the following i was able to build and archive the app. I found these command on this link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12725

```
flutter clean
rm -rf ios/Flutter/App.framework ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework
rm -rf /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gdzryurgzchazzddeyhdklwmefdq
flutter build ios
```